# How exactly order by works and which sorting process it uses

Tags: sql-server

which sorting process does order by uses in sql server

Comment: Either that information is available in the documentation or else Microsoft considers that proprietary information.  Why are you asking?

Comment: [Collation and unicode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15): "Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data"

Comment: That's like asking "how does electronic ignition work in a modern automobile". It just does - the exact implementation is something few really need to understand.